Calling the create method of a ModelViewSet from another ModelViewSet
I need to create objects of model B from the views.py file of A. I was able to do it using the serialiser of B (see # OLD METHOD using serializer) but I would like to know how to use the create method of viewset B from viewset A
In the function generate_drf_format, I tried to manually instantiate and invoke the create action in Viewset B but it's not working. I am getting the error message:

AttributeError: 'ViewSetB' object has no attribute 'request'

class ViewSetB(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = B.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BSerializer



 class ViewSetA(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
     queryset = A.objects.all()
     serializer_class = ASerializer
 
     def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         form_data = request.data
 
         # map front-end request to DRF model
         mapped_data = generate_drf_format(form_data)
 
         serializer = self.get_serializer(data=mapped_data)
         serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
         self.perform_create(serializer)
         headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
         return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)




def generate_drf_format(form_data):
    participants_ids = []
    if 'participants' in form_data:
        participants_list = form_data['participants']

        if len(participants_list) > 0:
            request = HttpRequest()
            for participant_data in participants_list:
                    request.data = participant_data

                    # Manually instantiate and invoke action in Viewset B
                    viewset_b = UserViewSet()
                    viewset_b.create(request=request)

                    # OLD METHOD using serializer
                    # b_serializer = BSerializer(data=participant_data)
                    # if b_serializer.is_valid():
                    #     b_serializer.save()
                    #     participants_ids.append(b_serializer.data['id'])
                    # else:
                    #     return Response(b_serializer.errors)

    new_data = generate_some_obj(form_data, participants_ids)
    return new_data

Any suggestion of how to call the create method of one viewset from another viewset

Please edit your question. There is no ViewSetB in your example.

The method handlers for a class ViewSet are only bound to the corresponding actions at the point of finalizing the view, using the .as_view() method.
Hence to manually call a method handler of a class ViewSet, you must first finalize the class ViewSet.
viewset_b = ViewSetB.as_view({"post": "create"})
viewset_b(request=request) #[1]

[1] Ensure that the request object is completely instantiated and will not cause a permission error, method not allowed error or any other type of error.
